# Spring Quartz Task firing multiple times in error

Tags: spring, tomcat, struts2, quartz-scheduler

We have a Quartz job scheduled in a Struts2 web app using spring which is meant to fire every morning at 6am. The problem we have is the job is firing 4 times at 6am. We are running the same task in an older version of the software without any issues. The only difference between the 2 is the one running correctly runs Spring 3.05 and Quartz 1.8.3 while the newer version runs Spring 3.2.13 and Quartz 2.2.1. They are both running on Tomcat 7 and Java 1.7

Here's the relevant web.xml snippet

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Relevant Spring config is :

```
<bean name="dailyReminders"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.sample.SendReminderTask" />
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
    <property name="jobDataMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="patientService" value-ref="patientService" />
            <entry key="textService" value-ref="textService" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dailyReminderTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="dailyReminders"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 6 * * ?"/>
</bean>

<bean  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="dailyReminders" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="dailyReminderTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I checked the tomcat Servers.xml it only has one host which I know has been an issue for others. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I just had a look at the latest log and found this entry:

```
Exception in thread "org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_QuartzSchedulerThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution
at org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl.isConcurrentExectionDisallowed(JobDetailImpl.java:388)
at org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.acquireNextTriggers(RAMJobStore.java:1428)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
... 3 more
```

I checked and the class is in the included library and I couldn't find any other quartz jars on the server. I don't know why it is throwing the error. Is it an incompatibility with Spring?

**UPDATE 2: ** When the tomcat starts I see the following in the catalina.out log

```
Jun 23, 2015 5:05:38 AM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
INFO: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
Jun 23, 2015 5:05:38 AM org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean startScheduler
INFO: Starting Quartz Scheduler now
.
.
.
Jun 23, 2015 5:05:39 AM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
INFO: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
Jun 23, 2015 5:05:39 AM org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean startScheduler
INFO: Starting Quartz Scheduler now
.
.
.
Jun 23, 2015 5:05:43 AM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start
INFO: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
Jun 23, 2015 5:05:43 AM org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean startScheduler
INFO: Starting Quartz Scheduler now
```

Why is the scheduler starting three times a few seconds apart?

This is driving me nuts, any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: Is that in cluster ?

Comment: No cluster, just a single Tomcat server.